# Inserting arrays with nested structure in KSQLDB

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am trying to insert nested array objects to KSQL table. My table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE nlpArticlesTrain ("articleText" VARCHAR,
  "ner" ARRAY<STRUCT<"text" VARCHAR, "label" VARCHAR>>,
  "rel" ARRAY<STRUCT<"head" VARCHAR, "tail" VARCHAR, "rel" VARCHAR, "prob" DOUBLE>>)
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'nlpArticlesTrain', PARTITIONS=1, REPLICAS=1, VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

I know I can push using standard Kafka producer with Avro support but I am looking for a way to `INSER INTO VALUES` to the table so that the stream/topic underneath is populated. From the [documentation of query with structured data](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/query-with-structured-data/) I am missing an example for insert.

`INSERT INTO nlpArticlesTrain (articleText,ner,rel) VALUES ("string", [{..}],[{..}])` does not work.

A more concrete example:

```
INSERT INTO nlpArticlesTrain (articleText,ner,rel) VALUES ("some", [{'text': 'The Mexican Ministry of Health', 'label': 'ORG'}, {'text': 'Tuesday', 'label': 'DATE'}, {'text': 'at least 29', 'label': 'CARDINAL'}], [{'head': 'The Mexican Ministry of Health', 'tail': 'Tuesday', 'rel': 'subsidiary', 'prob': 0.3873162269592285}])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what version of ksqlDB you're on.  Later versions support the `ARRAY` and `STRUCT` constructors, which is what you need. For example:

```sql
CREATE STREAM TEST (K STRING KEY, A ARRAY<STRUCT<FOO INT>>) 
    WITH (kafka_topic='test_topic', value_format='JSON');

INSERT INTO TEST (A) VALUES (ARRAY[
   STRUCT(FOO := 1),
   STRUCT(FOO := 2)
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my OP is not about arrays, its about nested struct in arrays.

Comment: both STRUCT and ARRAY

Comment: Thanks, quick check seems to work after an update to latest KsqlDB